# phone battery usage at various audio volumes

Tags: power, audio, android

I was wondering if anyone knows how the power output of my phone varies with the level I set it at. Lets say I plug my phone up to a stereo to play music and I set my phone volume to 5/10 and then only adjust the stereo as needed (lets say 80% gives me the volume I want). How much power would I save if I did this vs. setting my phone volume to 10/10 and then only needing the stereo volume to say 60%. I was wondering if anyone has any idea the differences in power usage that the different phone settings would have from a battery saving perspective.

Comment: It's really impossible to say. The only way to determine this is via empirical testing.

Comment: Easier than some might say. You need to know which audio amplifier ic your cell phone uses. Then grab it's datasheet.

Comment: Take a look at breakdown for the Wolfson Electronic devices which are sometimes used. The reality is this is negligible. LCD and other items take much more.

Answer (score 1):

First, you would want to measure the load the stereo presents to the phone. Headphones/speakers present a lower impedance (tens of ohms) than an audio input jack of a stereo/TV.

Any battery savings will be minimal when connected to a higher impedance load (hundreds or thousands of ohms). You also may not be able to measure this impedance with a multimeter since there may be a DC blocking capacitor on your stereo's input.

tl;dr: Any power savings are negligible.